# making ribbon center using css

Tags: html, css, ribbon

Im creating a ribbon using css. the page it is on is [FOUND HERE](http://www.xclo.mobi/xclo2/)

*I know the rest of my page needs more work but right this second I am focusing on the ribbon.*

I need it to be **auto 90% and center** no matter what the screen size. at the moment it is cut off on the left a little and not center.

my css code:

```
.ribbon {
   width: 90%;
   position: absolute;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 15px!important;
   background: #2cdb1c;
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#2cdb1c), to(#618028));
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2cdb1c, #618028);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #2cdb1c, #618028);
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #2cdb1c, #618028);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #2cdb1c, #618028);
   background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #2cdb1c 0%, #618028 100%);
   -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(000,000,000,0.3) 0 1px 1px;
   -moz-box-shadow: rgba(000,000,000,0.3) 0 1px 1px;
   box-shadow: rgba(000,000,000,0.3) 0 1px 1px;
   font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica, sans-serif;
   }
.ribbon h1 {
   font-size: 23px!important;
   color: #000000;
   text-shadow: #b9c9b5 0 1px 0;
   margin:0px;
   padding: 15px 10px;
   }
.ribbon:before, .ribbon:after {
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   display: block;
   bottom: -1em;
   border: 1.5em solid #379c27;
   z-index: -1;
   }
.ribbon:before {
   left: -2em;
   border-right-width: 1.5em;
   border-left-color: transparent;
   -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(000,000,000,0.4) 1px 1px 1px;
   -moz-box-shadow: rgba(000,000,000,0.4) 1px 1px 1px;
   box-shadow: rgba(000,000,000,0.4) 1px 1px 1px;
   }
.ribbon:after {
   right: -2em;
   border-left-width: 1.5em;
   border-right-color: transparent;
   -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(000,000,000,0.4) -1px 1px 1px;
   -moz-box-shadow: rgba(000,000,000,0.4) -1px 1px 1px;
   box-shadow: rgba(000,000,000,0.4) -1px 1px 1px;
   }
.ribbon .ribbon-content:before, .ribbon .ribbon-content:after {
   border-color: #000000 transparent transparent transparent;
   position: absolute;
   display: block;
   border-style: solid;
   bottom: -1em;
   content: '';
   }
.ribbon .ribbon-content:before {
   left: 0;
   border-width: 1em 0 0 1em;
   }
.ribbon .ribbon-content:after {
   right: 0;
   border-width: 1em 1em 0 0;
   }
.ribbon-stitches-top {
   margin-top:2px;
   border-top: 1px dashed rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
   }
.ribbon-stitches-bottom {
   margin-bottom:2px;
   border-top: 1px dashed rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
   }
```

Can someone please help me? thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could actually center it based on percentage and absolutely:

```
.ribbon {
    position: absolute;
    width: 90%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -45%;
}
```

Comment: why do you use an obsolete hack and don't you use position:relative and keep .ribbon in the flow ?

Comment: Its actually not a hack. Using javascript to center it would be a hack. if he needs the banner to be absolutely positioned and centered this fills his need hence why my answer is approved.

Comment: javascript would do exactly the same thing you do, ............. but the good advise would be to explain the relation of parent(not  position:static; ) with childs (position:absolute;)........... So your answers comes really usefull for him.......... Besides , i did not noticed he needed absolute positionning in the first place here to have his ribbon displayed correctly : http://www.xclo.mobi/xclo2/ ? position:relative does it and keep it in the flow.

Comment: I do not believe you disagree, but you might have misunderstood me. some examples that do not all relay on absolute : http://codepen.io/tag/ribbon

Answer (score 0):

It can't be positioned as `absolute`. Remove that. Make sure its parent has 100% `width` and then set `margin:0 auto`;

Answer (score 0):

You could put your entire ribbon inside a divide. Then instead of centering the ribbon just give it a width of 100%.

```
ribbon_divide {
     margin: 0 auto;
     width: 90%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your ribbon with a div.

```
<div style="width:90%;margin:0 auto;">
<div class="ribbon"><div class="ribbon-stitches-top"></div><strong class="ribbon-content"><h1>Xclo.mobi</h1></strong><div class="ribbon-stitches-bottom"></div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap ribbon element and set width=100% for ribbon.

```
.ribbon-wrapper {
   position: relative;
   width: 90%;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
.ribbon {
    width: 100%

}
```

```
<div class="ribbon-wrapper">
    <!-- Your ribbon html code -->
</div>
```